# child class with rtti from base class with no rtti

Tags: c++, linker, clang, rtti, clang++

I need to call `void foo(const base &)` from `libfoo.a` which comes compiled with `-fno-rtti`. I need to pass my `child` class that's required to inherent from `base` to override virtual member functions, this `child` class must exist in a compilation setting where RTTI must be enabled because of other requirements, but if a do that the linker throws:

> undefined reference to `typeinfo for base`

Do I access `typeinfo for base` just by inhereting from `base`? Is there a way to proceed in this situation? how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subclassing class from shared library compiled with -fno-rtti](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101859/subclassing-class-from-shared-library-compiled-with-fno-rtti)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility if you can declare a non-rtti object as a member of an rtti object is to create a 3rd helper class to translate between the rtti and non-rtti classes.

```
class child;

/* RttiHelper compiled WITHOUT RTTI support */
class RttiHelper: public base {
public:
    child &child_;
    RttiHelper(const child &c): child_(c) { }
    virtual int basefunc() override;
    // ...
};

/* child compiled WITH RTTI support */
class child {
public:
    RttiHelper base_;
    child(): base_(*this) { }
    virtual int basefunc() { /* ... */ }
    void otherfunc(int x) { base_(x); }  // example call of non-virtual base class method
};

// implementation of RttiHelper relay functions needs to come after child class is defined
inline int RttiHelper::basefunc() { return child_.basefunc(); }
```